# Why is my Application.XLookup in VBA giving "Type Mismatch" Error?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, xlookup

EDIT: Changed my code to use boolean logic instead of concatenating but am still getting the same error.

I am trying to use the application.xlookup in vba, and add extra criteria by concatenating the formula inside this code.

```
Sub employeelookup()
 SalesForm.BHSDEMPLOYEETD.Value = Application.XLookup(1, (Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("E:E") = SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.Value) * (Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("AI2:AI5") = SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD.Value), Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("F:F"))
End Sub
```

I have tried changing the parentheses and messing with the order but I was getting syntax errors. The code above should work in theory but I can't figure out where the Type Mismatch error is coming from.

Comment: `Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("E:E") & Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range.("AI:AI")`: you can't concatenate two multi-cell ranges like this.

Comment: @BigBen So i should just be using boolean logic to add extra criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put everything in arrays and loop those to find the value:

```
Sub employeelookup()
    Dim mn_num As Double
    mn_num = Val(SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.Value)
    Dim rec As String
    rec = SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD.Value
    
    Dim lkpmnArr As Variant
    lkpmnArr = Intersect(Worksheets("TELEDATA").UsedRange, Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("E:E")).Value
    
    Dim lkprecArr As Variant
    lkprecArr = Intersect(Worksheets("TELEDATA").UsedRange, Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("AI:AI")).Value
    
    Dim lkotArr As Variant
    lkotArr = Intersect(Worksheets("TELEDATA").UsedRange, Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("F:F")).Value
    
    Dim otpt As String
    otpt = "Not Found"
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(lkpmnArr, 1) To UBound(lkpmnArr, 1)
        If lkpmnArr(i, 1) = mn_num And lkprecArr(i, 1) = rec Then
            otpt = lkotArr(i, 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    
    SalesForm.BHSDEMPLOYEETD.Value = otpt
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there! Just popped that code in and it came up with "Method 'Intersect' of object'_Global' Failed"

Comment: @cheese10234, yes I had a typo.  Refresh and run the latest edit.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Evaluate`:

```vb
Sub employeelookup()
    'Whether v1 and/or v2 are quoted depends on if numeric or text
    '  here <v1> is numeric and <v2> is not
    Const FRM As String = "XLOOKUP(<v1>&<v2>,E:E&AI:AI,H:H)"
    Dim res, f
    
    'replace the placeholders in the formula with values from your form
    f = Replace(FRM, "<v1>", val(SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.value))
    f = Replace(f, "<v2>", SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD.value)
    
    'evaluate in context of sheet TELEDATA
    res = Worksheets("TELEDATA").Evaluate(f)
    
    If IsError(res) Then  'if got an error then no match was made
        Debug.Print "No match"
    Else
        Debug.Print res
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I am a little confused as to what to put in the green quotation slots, can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "green quotation slots"

Comment: ```(" & v1 & "&""" & v2 & """,E:E&AI:AI,F:F)")```

Comment: Thank you for the timely responses, I'm "self-taught" and some of this really throws me through a loop.

Comment: An example formula used on a worksheet might look like `=XLOOKUP(4 & "Val004",E:E&AI:AI,F:F)`  The two values you're pulling from your form need to be substituted in there and that's what `v1` and `v2` are doing.  If you're still having problems getting it working then post an example of a worksheet formula with values that work for you.

Comment: My original formula is this:

```
Sub salesoriginlookup()
SalesForm.BHSDSALESORIGINTD.Value = Application.XLookup(Val(SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.Value), Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("E:E"), Worksheets("TELEDATA").Range("W:W"))
End Sub
```

This works, however the "SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF.Value" is duplicated on the worksheet its pulling from, so I am trying to also search by "SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD.value" so i am getting not just the customers info but the info for the exact record. 

TLDR, I am trying to add an extra criteria into my XLookup formula for a more specific result.

Comment: Updated with a cleaner approach which avoids the concatenation to build the formula.  Try to the a working formula *on the worksheet* using a couple of example values, and post that.

Comment: This is the formula.
=XLOOKUP(1,(E2:E5=AK4)*(AI2:AI5=AM4),H2:H5)

This works on a worksheet, basically trying to translate this to work in vba

Comment: So I want to do the above formula while changing "AK4" to the value that is in textbox "SalesForm.BHSDMAINNUMBERLF", and "AM4" to the value in textbox "SalesForm.BHSDRECORDTD".

Comment: What type of values are in those textboxes?  Numeric/text/date etc ?  Did you try the code I posted?

Comment: i did and nothing came up at all, no error code or anything. just numeric, i believe. i could format them though if thats the issue however.

Comment: "nothing came up" - you mean there was no output in the Immediate pane in the VB editor (Ctrl+G to show)?  Corrected above to use Col H as the return value.